# access by active record query with join table record in has_many :through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join, has-many-through

I have item, region and category table they are join through item_region ans item_category table their relationship is as follow

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :item_region    
  has_many :region, :through => :item_region    
  has_many :item_category    
  has_many :category, :through => :item_category    

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :category    
  has_many :item, ::through => :item_category    

class ItemRegion < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :item    
  belongs_to :region    
end    

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :item, :through => :item_category    
  has_many :item_category    

class ItemCategory < ActiveRecord::Base    
  belongs_to :item    
  belongs_to :category    
end
```

I want to find all fields of item and category_name and region_name from region_id,category_id and item_id using join table.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope I got this one correct(that's why I'm posting this as a comment and not as an answer). What about obtaining the required item, then the desired region and category from it. `item = Item.find(item_id`, then `region = item.regions.where(:id => region_id)` and `category = item.categories.where(:id => category_id)`.

Comment: thanks for your reply,but when I fired second query               region = item.regions.where(:id => region_id) it give's error because item is array so it give me "undefine method regions".

Comment: Hmm..sorry, but `item` is not an array. `item = Item.find(item_id)` will give you an `item` object of class `Item`. You can confirm that by `Item.find(item_id).class`. The error "undefined method regions" is because you have not set up the associations' name properly. For instance, in Item model it should be `has_many :regions, :through => :item_regions` and `has_many :categories, :through => :item_categories`. You'll need to do `item.region.where ...` but that is not a good practice since an item has many regions. Its intuitive to do `object.collections` for a has many association.

Comment: The gist is if its a has many association, you are better off providing plural form. Note that Rails will still function with above code but that doesn't follow CoC(convention over configuration) principle of Rails. If you follow the convention, you wouldn't have to do a lot of configurations. Check the examples here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many . Meanwhile I'll post that as an answer  so you can accept it if (and only if) it helped solving your question.

Comment: sorry prasvin when i ran item = Item.find(item_id).class and then raise item.inspect it gives me arry.I mean to say that item = Item.find(item_id) give array of items and then I do             region = item.regions.where(:id => region_id) here item is array find from first query....hope you understan and thanks for reply.

Comment: "I mean to say that item = Item.find(item_id) give array of items"...are you sure ? Can you double check that ? Try doing that in your Rails console and post the obtained output.

Comment: yes i am sure it is array I check in console i think i can use include@items = Item.find(:all, :include => [:region, :category], :conditions => " items.id => item_ids AND regions.id => region_id AND categories.id => category_id") but getting following error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I got this one correct. What about obtaining the required item, then the desired region and category from it.

```
item = Item.find(item_id)
region = item.regions.where(:id => region_id) 
category = item.categories.where(:id => category_id)
```

Another suggestion, you are better off providing plural form for your associations. Its intuitive to do `object.collections` for a `has_many` association. Note that Rails will still function with above code but that doesn't follow CoC(convention over configuration) principle of Rails. If you follow the convention, you wouldn't have to do a lot of configurations.

Check the examples here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many

Personally, I'd prefer to have my associations in Item model as :

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :item_regions    
  has_many :regions, :through => :item_regions    
  has_many :item_categories    
  has_many :categories, :through => :item_categories
```